# Use State is Not Updating The dom immediately. When I call the function clearLocalStorage, My Dom is not updating, although it is updating on reload,

Tags: javascript, reactjs

its not working
Whenever I call the function clearLocalStorage, My Dom is not updating, although it is updating on reload. The blog variable is updating elsewhere tho, but changes aren't reflecting on dom. I Have tried all the things from using hooks to giving keys and whatnot. Trying to Solve this from past 1 or 2 days. no success till now. I'm at beginner level learning react.  In my previous or other projects, The useStateHook is working perfectly fine. of course it must bee working here fine too but the dom ughh. One more questionwhat is equivalent to constructor in function based components?

```
import Blogs from "./components/Blogs";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import About from "./components/About";
import LoadingBar from "react-top-loading-bar";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import {
 BrowserRouter as Router,
 Switch,
 HashRouter,
 Route,
 Routes,
 Link,
 BrowserRouter,
} from "react-router-dom";
import BlogShow from "./components/BlogShow";
import CreateBlog from "./components/CreateBlog";

function App() {
 const data = {
   status: "ok",
   totalResults: 3,
   articles: [
     {
       id: 1,
       title: "FootBall On Rise",
       blog: "In USA, The Rise of Football became significantly noticable after the start of hero indian super leauge, moreover the broadcasting of football became more regular. ",
     },
   ],
 };

 const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
 const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState(
   localStorage.getItem("data")
     ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"))
     : data
 );
 const changeProgress = (progress) => {
   setProgress(progress);
 };

 const clearLocalStorage = () => {
   localStorage.removeItem("data");
   console.log(blogs);
   setBlogs(data);
 };
 return (
   <>
     <HashRouter>
       <NavBar />
       <LoadingBar
         color="#ff1944"
         progress={progress}
         onLoaderFinished={() => setProgress(0)}
         shadow={true}
         height={4}
         transitionTime={300}
         loaderSpeed={500}
         waitingTime={500}
       />
       <Routes>
         <Route
           path="/"
           element={<Blogs data={blogs} setProgress={changeProgress} />}
         />
         <Route
           path="/home"
           element={<Blogs data={blogs} setProgress={changeProgress} />}
         />
         <Route
           path="/home"
           element={<Blogs data={blogs} setProgress={changeProgress} />}
         />
         <Route
           path="/blogs"
           element={<Blogs data={blogs} setProgress={changeProgress} />}
         />
         <Route
           path="/blogshow/:id"
           element={<BlogShow data={blogs} setProgress={changeProgress} />}
         />
         <Route
           path="/create"
           element={<CreateBlog data={blogs} setProgress={changeProgress} />}
         />
         <Route
           path="/about"
           element={<About setProgress={changeProgress} key={"f"} />}
         />
       </Routes>
       <div className="container">
         <button onClick={clearLocalStorage} className="btn btn-primary">
           Clear
         </button>
       </div>
     </HashRouter>
   </>
 );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code of one of your component which are used to display blogs data.

For your second question, there is no constructor equivalent in function based components. Constructor are only used in Javasript class. What would you like to do with a constructor in a function?

Comment: Thanks, After Hours of head banging, i finally found my mistake. Like you said I shoulh've put the child component, The problem was there, I was setting the state in useEffect [] which only called one time on component rendering. I should've used empty useEffect. One More Question if you don't mind. What exactly useEffect hook does, and what does the syntax means of returning nothing or empty array or a function in that?